# How can I get a string from a function

Tags: php

So, this is my code:

```
class Functions{
    public static function login($email,$password){
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $password = $_GET['password'];
        if(isset($_GET['submit']) AND isset($email) AND isset($password)){
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['nume'] = $row["name"];
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row["admin"];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
                $_SESSION['points'] = $row["points"];
            }else{
                $errortxt = "Invalid Login Credentials";
                $error = true;
            }
        }
        return $error;
    }
}
```

In my HTML file I'm calling for the function like this:

```
Function::login($email,$password);
```

But I'm wondering how can I get the $errortxt string to echo in the HTML file.

Thanks!

Comment: Encapsulate those values in an array and return it, like this: `return array($error, $errortxt);`

Comment: Should it be `Functions::login($email,$password);` ?

Comment: I would return an stdClass object, including either the error-messages or the successful result. - or an array as @RajdeepPaul suggested.

Comment: like this: `$response['txt'] = "MEssage"; $reponse['error'] = true;` by creating an array

Comment: The simplest solution would just be to return the text, and use that to test if an error had been caught. If text is returned, then you can assume `$error = true;`. More generally, you should throw an exception containing the message and catch that in the calling code.

Comment: Maybe instead set `$_SESSION['errortxt']` while still returning `true` or `false`.  As it stands `$error` is undefined if login is successful.

Comment: Getting the error text from your function is probably the least of your woes. 1. you're prone to SQL injection attacks [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/), 2. You overwrite your function params with GET variables at the first instance, 3. Where does the `$conn` variable come from?, 4. You return `$error` but it may not be set if nothing is posted.

Comment: @R.Chappell For 2,3,4 yeah. I know. But how can I prevent myself from SQL injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a simple fix:

```
class Functions{
public static function login($email,$password){
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['errortxt'] = "";
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    if(isset($_GET['submit']) AND isset($email) AND isset($password)){
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['nume'] = $row["name"];
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $row["id"];
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $row["admin"];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
            $_SESSION['points'] = $row["points"];
        }else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['errortxt'] = "Invalid Login Credentials";
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
}
```

And you need to call it this way:

```
$fnCallStatus = Function::login($email,$password); //Now you have the response;
if($fnCallStatus['error']) //we have an error
{
    echo $fnCallStatus['errortxt']; //we print the message
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I fixed little bit your code because it lacks good coding principles and good taste (calling superglobal $_GET variable will always get you something after request despite you place something else into function parameters).

```
class Functions{

    public static function login($email,$password)
    {
        $error['is'] = true;

        $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
        $password = md5(htmlspecialchars($password));

        if(!empty($email) AND !empty($password))
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['nume'] = $row["name"];
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row["admin"];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
                $_SESSION['points'] = $row["points"];
            } else {
                $error['mismatch'] = "Email or password does not match.";
                return $error;
            }
        } else {
            $error['empty'] = "Please fill all login fields. Thank you";
            return $error;
        }
    }
}

$error = Function::login($_GET['email'],$_GET['password']);

if($error['is'])
{
    if ($error['mismatch']) {
        echo $error['mismatch'];
    } elseif ($error['empty']) {
        echo $error['empty']
    }
}
```

Your function also always return $error despite none occurred. I fixed that and function return error only in not query case.

Functions can return arrays. So if you need to set multiple fields with different text, you can place into array anything you like. This solution is more buletproof.